# How to get maximized size of frame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I set maximized frame: `setExtendedState(getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_BOTH);`

Now how I can get this size, because when I call `getSize()` or `getPreferredSize` it returns `0 0`?

Comment: *"How to get ... size of frame?"*  Why on earth would you need to know?  1) Use layouts for components  2) Do custom painting in a `JComponent` or `JPanel` and only query the size when painting.  BTW - for better help sooner, state the goal (e.g. 'make components fit') as opposed to the strategy (e.g. 'get size of frame').

Comment: I need this to set size of panel which is in this frame to have size as have this frame

Comment: Simply adding a panel to a frame will cause the panel to become the size of the content area.

Comment: but I dont want to this panel have content size. I wanna it bigger as is the frame where is this panel

Comment: While the first sentence makes some sense, I don't understand the 2nd sentence.  Can you phrase it differently?

Comment: sorry my english isnt very good :( . I want size of panel which is in frame as big (large) as is frame.

Comment: That is exactly the effect that putting a panel directly into a frame has.  If the question was not answered, I'd add some code to prove it.

Comment: ok you can do it now. really thx for helping me with Java SWING :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You will get the maximized size correctly after the `setVisible(true);` is executed.

```
public NewJFrame() {                            // Constructor
    initComponents();
    this.setExtendedState( getExtendedState() | JFrame.MAXIMIZED_VERT | Frame.MAXIMIZED_HORIZ);
    // height and width still prints the original values 
    System.out.println(this.getSize().height + " " + this.getSize().width); 
}

....

public static void main(String args[]) {        // main
    java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            NewJFrame foo = new NewJFrame();
            foo.setVisible(true);
            // after setVisible(true) actual maximized values
            System.out.println(foo.getSize().height + " " + foo.getSize().width);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want size of panel which is in frame as big (large) as is frame.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class FullSizePanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // this is the panel we want to fill the entire content area
                // of the  parent frame.
                JPanel redFullSizePanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
                // make it true to the first part of the attribute name
                redFullSizePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Full Size Panel");
                // 1) The default layout for a content pane is BorderLayout
                // 2) A component added to a BL with no layout constraint ends
                //     up in the CENTER
                // 3) A component in the CENTER of a BL takes the full space
                //     (that is not used up by components in the EAST, WEST,
                //     NORTH & SOUTH).
                f.add( redFullSizePanel );

                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.pack();
                f.setSize(400,400);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

---

What layout IS useful?

> grid or box layout with 1 column and x rows

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

class FullSizePanel {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                // grid or box layout with 1 column and x rows
                LayoutManager lm = new GridLayout(0,1,5,5);
                // this is the panel we want to fill the entire content area
                // of the  parent frame.
                JPanel redFullSizePanel = new JPanel(lm);
                // make it true to the first part of the attribute name
                redFullSizePanel.setBackground(Color.RED);

                for (int ii=1; ii<6; ii++) {
                    redFullSizePanel.add(new JLabel("Label " + ii));
                    redFullSizePanel.add(new JButton("Button " + ii));
                }

                JFrame f = new JFrame("Full Size Panel");
                // 1) The default layout for a content pane is BorderLayout
                // 2) A component added to a BL with no layout constraint ends
                //     up in the CENTER
                // 3) A component in the CENTER of a BL takes the full space
                //     (that is not used up by components in the EAST, WEST,
                //     NORTH & SOUTH.
                f.add( redFullSizePanel );

                f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
                f.pack();
                f.setSize(400,400);
                f.setLocationByPlatform(true);
                f.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: but border layout isnt useful in this frame

Comment: BE SPECIFIC!!  Especially when you are not sure of the language.  In this case, why is it not useful?  What layout IS useful?

Comment: grid or box layout with 1 column and x rows

Comment: Are you referring to the layout of the `redFullSizePanel`?  Again, be  S-P-E-C-I-F-I-C.  It has nothing to do with language and everything to do with simple logic.  Imagine I am not able to read your mind nor sitting in front of your computer.  (See edit based on guess of what you mean - and note that I don't *like* guessing.)

Comment: The original question is: "Hot to get maximized size of frame?" @AndrewThompson, you didn't set the frame state to maximized, nor did you show how to get maximized frame size. Your post is not helpful, at least not to me.

Comment: @ViktorFonic  It is unlikely good answers would result from this question.  Ask your own question.

Comment: I disagree. The question is good and I stumbled upon it as I was searching for the same answer myself.

Comment: *"I disagree."*  Good for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try getting maximum "generic" window size. Since your application is maximized, it should produce the same result:

```
GraphicsEnvironment env = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment();
Dimension screenDimension = env.getMaximumWindowBounds().getSize();
```

Don't forget that your window also has so called insets:

```
Insets insets = frame.getInsets();
final int left = insets.left;
final int right = insets.right;
final int top = insets.top;
final int bottom = insets.bottom;

final int width = screenDimension.width - left - right;
final int height = screenDimension.height - top - bottom;
```